# XSLT datetime formatting

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

If i have the following:

```
<showtime><time>2017-01-01T15:30:01.331Z</time><time>2017-01-02T20:30:00.995Z</time></showtime>
```

Is there a way to format the datetime using xslt so that it will both round the millisecond and change last section to just 2 digits?

Outcome:

```
<showtime><time>2017-01-01T15:30:01.33Z</time><time>2017-01-02T20:30:01.00Z</time></showtime>
```

Comment: It looks like this is about more than just formatting . What would be the expected result of `<time>1999-12-31T23:59:59.995Z</time>`?

Comment: P.S. Please select either XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, not both.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your response and i'll remember to just tag one from now on. relating to your question, yes it is def more than formatting as it needs to be rounded, the expected full solution should result in:         <time>2000-01-01T00:00:00.00Z</time>

Comment: OK, but which one will you be using for this one? The answer will be fundamentally different depending on your XSLT version.

Comment: v2.0 is what i am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, format-dateTime in XSLT 2.0 does essentially what you want. Unfortunately there are some rough edges in the handling of seconds and milliseconds. There are two separate picture elements for formatting the seconds and fractional seconds. In principle '[s01],[f001]' formats two digits for the seconds and three for the fractional seconds, separated by a comma. But the complication arises with values like 23.9999.

XSLT 2.0 says, "In the case of the fractional seconds component, the value is rounded to the specified size as if by applying the function round-half-to-even(fractional-seconds, max-width)." However you interpret it, this doesn't give a sensible answer for rounding a fractional seconds value of .9999 to three digits. There is no mention of rolling any overflow into the seconds value (and potentially then into the minutes value, hours value and so on).

In the Functions and Operators 3.1 specification this bug was fixed using the path of least resistance: the spec was changed to say that the value is truncated to the specified width.

If it's really important to you to achieve rounding in such a way that 2016-12-31T23:59:59.9999Z is rounded to 2017-01-01T00:00:00.00, then you're going to have to write the logic yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If truncation is acceptable and true rounding is not required, this simple solution works across XSLT 1.0 and 2.0:

```
<xsl:template match="showtime/time">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(., 1, 22), 'Z')"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I think the expected output makes it quite clear that mere truncation is **not** acceptable.

Comment: Not knowing the context of the question it's hard to tell whether truncation would be a problem. If we shave off precision anyway, it seems that being off by at most 10 milliseconds instead of 5 milliseconds might be acceptable.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for the reply, i actually do have what you responded with currently as a bandage, but wanted to see if there are full solution for rounding. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In **XSLT 2** you can use such functions as *format-date*, *format-dateTime* and *format-time*.

Unfortunately, these functions take *xs:date*, *xs:dateTime* and *xs:time* values respectively (not just strings).
So as the first thing you have to select respective date / time substrings
(from the source content) and create these date / time variables.

Then you can output these values in any format, specified with *picture* argument.

Comment: Does the picture argument support how many millisecond digits should be displayed? I don't think so.

Comment: How exactly would you *format* a time of `20:30:00.995` so that the result is `20:30:01.00`?

Comment: @ThomasW Yes, it does. But it will not roll over the seconds (not to mention the minutes, the hours, the day, the month or the year).

Comment: Rather than continue this thread in comments, I've addressed the questions raised here in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's surprising how difficult and awkward this task can be, despite all the date/time functions provided by XPath 2.0.

Anyway, this is what I came up with. Note that this is done in two separate and independent steps: first we calculate the rounded dateTime value, then we format it. Unlike what others have said, formatting is the trivial part here.

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="time">
    <xsl:variable name="seconds" select="3600 * hours-from-dateTime(.) + 60 * minutes-from-dateTime(.) + seconds-from-dateTime(.)" />
    <xsl:variable name="round-seconds" select="round($seconds * 100) div 100" />

    <xsl:variable name="dur" select="xs:dayTimeDuration(concat('PT', $seconds, 'S'))" />
    <xsl:variable name="round-dur" select="xs:dayTimeDuration(concat('PT', $round-seconds, 'S'))" />

    <xsl:variable name="new-dateTime" select="xs:dateTime(.) - $dur + $round-dur" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime($new-dateTime, '[Y0001]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01].[f01][ZN]')" /> 
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```