# Current-dateTime() Microsecond precision Issue

Tags: datetime, xslt, saxon

Previously, when using the function *current-dateTime()* [XPATH 2.0 & SAXON 9], I would get a value like `2023-07-15T13:11:43.618+02:00`.
However after migration to [XPATH 3.1 & SAXON 10], now for the same function I would get a value like `2023-07-15T13:11:43.618557+02:00`.

So there are these extra decimal values for the Microseconds which I believe was done for greater accuracy. However, I need up to only 3 digits for ms.

Is there a way to restore the previous behaviour?

Comment: I don't think you can change the behavior of the function, but you should be able to round the result - see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45341026/xslt-datetime-formatting.

Answer (score 2):

The precision maintained by the date/time data types is implementation-defined, and as you have noted, it has been increased in Saxon over time. In fact, according to the documentation at https://saxonica.com/documentation12/index.html#!changes/functions31/9.8-9.9 the precision held by the data types was increased from microseconds to nanoseconds between 9.8 and 9.9, but the change to current-dateTime() might have been made later than this. It probably coincided with Saxon's switch to Java 8 as the JDK baseline, allowing us to take advantage of the new date/time types (such as `ZonedDateTime`) in Java 8.

The easiest way to reduce the precision is probably by using the `format-dateTime()` function. Another way would be to extract the seconds component using `seconds-from-dateTime()`, then use decimal arithmetic `($value - round($value, 3))` to work out how much time to subtract, and then use (date - duration) arithmetic to subtract the relevant number of microseconds.

Or, more crudely, you could convert to a string and then use a regular expression replacement.

Comment: It should be noted that formatting the dateTime will truncate it, not round it.

Comment: Hello @MichaelKay, I am able to resolve the issue for now using the `format-dateTime()` as 'format-dateTime(current-dateTime(), "[Y]-[M01]-[D01]T[H01]:[m01]:[s01].[f001][Z]")' for now and getting precision up to 3 decimal points. Thank you so much for your valuable input.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Indeed so. There was actually a bug here in the 3.0 spec, which said the value should be rounded, but didn't say how you're supposed to round 59.999999 seconds. So 3.1 changed it to specify truncation.